# When I edit and save the CSV file through MS Excel, I want the Python script to update the file to the newly saved version

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

So I have a python script that will be running 24/7. Let's say the script reads a data.csv file with pandas.

> csv_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8')

Basically, every minute, I want the data.csv file to be updated to the currently saved version. For example: Let's say I create (and save) a new row to the data.csv file via MS-Excel, I would want the python script to detect that there's a newly added row without re-running the script.

Whenever I edit and save my data.csv file through MS-Excel, the python script doesn't detect the edit unless I close and rerun the script. I want  the script to automatically detect changes (every 60 seconds) to the csv.

I am not editing the csv file through Python, I will be editing the csv file through the MS-Excel user interface. Whenever I edit and save the csv file, I would like the Python script to update to the newly saved version without having to end and re-run the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the DataFrame every 60 seconds only when the file is modified:

```
import time
import os
import pandas as pd

SECONDS_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 60

print('csv_file updater started, press ctrl+c to exit')

try:
    last_modified_time = 0
    while True:
        new_modified_time = os.path.getmtime('data.csv')
        if new_modified_time > last_modified_time:
            csv_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
            last_modified_time = new_modified_time
            print('Dataframe Updated')
        
        time.sleep(SECONDS_BETWEEN_UPDATES)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('File update stopped by user')
```

Or if you just want to reread a csv every 60 seconds even if it was not modified, it becomes simpler:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

SECONDS_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 60

print('csv_file updater started, press ctrl+c to exit')

try:
    while:
        csv_file = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
        print('Dataframe Updated')
        time.sleep(SECONDS_BETWEEN_UPDATES)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('File update stopped by user')
```

Feel free to delete the print statements except the last one, if you don't want it replace it with `pass`.

Use Control+C to stop it running